# Get the First Parent(Volume Name or Drive Letter) from File using Java

Tags: java, file-io

> 1. First Question(Actually this one i need more)

I have searched through the google and i can't find how to do it .
For example i have the path :

```
C:\Users\Alexander\Desktop\Hello\Hello2\AudioFile.mp3
```

I want to get the name of the drive|volume containing this `File` , here it is **C**

What i was doing until now is :

```
new File(path).substring(0,1);
```

But what if the drive has two letters..

> 2. Second Question

What if i want to get the 3rd Parent of The File it it exists(**Desktop**).

---

Can you please provide an answer on the above?

---

Ps:
I have found `Paths.get(path).getRoot().toString()` but it returns `C:\`

Comment: A drive cannot have two letters. Valid drive letters in Windows range from A-Z. It can have a UNC path, which can be several letters and a pair of backslashes, but that's not what your question asks.

Comment: @Ken White The application will run on Linux and Mac OS also .

Comment: Then your question is inaccurate, and you're not looking for a *drive letter*.

Comment: @Ken White `O_O` Linux and Mac Os have not drive letters you mean?

Comment: No, Linux and Mac OSX do not have drive letters. They have volume names, which are multiple characters. Your title specifically asks for *drive letter*, and your code effort is trying to get a single letter. On either Linux or Mac OSX, your code would retrieve `/`.

Comment: @Ken White Thank you! i didn't knew that . I would be happy if you know a good article or paper describing Linux and Mac OSX volume names .

Comment: This is not a *find me a link* site. Google *Linux tutorial*.

Comment: @KenWhite I disagree , the links are for helping the questionnaire to find his answer . What if in the first place he/she didn't know where to search . I had a similar comment in a previous question . The commenter thought that i knew where to search . Hopefully there are people who understand it and provided me an explanation and some links which answered my question .

Comment: Sorry, but don't care whether you agree or not. The [help/on-topic] says that they're off-topic here. If you disagree, go to [meta] and ask to have the guidelines changed. Make sure you search thoroughly first, though, because it's been requested (and soundly thrashed) many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apache Commons IO](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io) has a [FilenameUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/) class and its [getPrefix()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) method does what you asked in question 1 .

I suppose You can find a work around for the 2 Question from Apache Commons IO.

```
String filename = "C:\Users\Alexander\Desktop\Hello\Hello2\AudioFile.mp3";

String prefix = FilenameUtils.getPrefix(filename);
System.out.println("Prefix: " + prefix);


String path = FilenameUtils.getPath(filename);
System.out.println("Path: " + path);

String fullPath = FilenameUtils.getFullPath(filename);
System.out.println("Full path: " + fullPath);

String name = FilenameUtils.getName(filename);
System.out.println("Name: " + name);

String baseName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(filename);
System.out.println("Base name: " + baseName);

String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(filename);
System.out.println("Extension: " + extension);
```

Comment: Give and some code .The links might be broken in the future. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS Please refer this example I think it would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks you Rajith :) The link is broken it has an extra `]` letter . Add some code on your answer so i maybe accept it . https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/io-commons/filenameutils/org-apache-commons-io-filenameutils-example/